# How to select limited images from gallery?

Tags: android, image-gallery

I want to allow user to select 3 images at a time from gallery. I have use `Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` to `true`,`requestCode` as 3.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);

                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        "Select Picture"), 3);
```

In `onActivityResult`:

```
if (requestCode == 3 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String[] all_Images = data.getStringArrayExtra("all_path");

           ...
}
```

how to restrict images to select?

Answer (score -1):

i dont think there is any way to do that via Intent.. but you can use library like[multiple image chooser](https://github.com/giljulio/android-multiple-image-picker) . in that there is method name "public boolean addImage(Image image)" in [Here](https://github.com/giljulio/android-multiple-image-picker/blob/master/picker/src/main/java/com/giljulio/imagepicker/ui/ImagePickerActivity.java) manage counter there.

```
public boolean addImage(Image image) {
       if(count< 3)
       {
        if(mSelectedImages.add(image)){

             ____________________
             __________CODE____________
              _____________________
                count++;
        }
       }
       else
       {
            Toast("You can not select anymore images");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I have seen this in Whats app, it's allow only 10 photos at a time.

Comment: yes but they have created there own gallery.. you can't do it through intent